# Publishing to Azure - ApplicationDbContext in Settings is Empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a little stuck here, and can't seem to get my database working on Azure after deploying, however everything works fine on my local machine.

What I've done so far is:

```
1) Logged into Azure
2) Created a website
3) Created a Database
4) Downloaded the 'Publish Profile' file
5) Enabled migrations on my App
7) Removed my DbContext class - NEVERMIND, I kept it. I removed the store initializer.
6) App > Publish > Import > (imported the publish profile)
```

However, when I go to Settings and check ApplicationDbContext, its blank. Furthermore, when I visit the site after it pushes to the cloud, I get the:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
```

...which is expected because the db isn't connected properly.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

ApplicationDbContext Class is as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext  : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
      public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DataContext") { }

      public DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Suggestion> Suggestions { get; set; }
      public DbSet<FollowUp> FollowUps { get; set; }

      public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Suggestions.Controllers.SuggestionBase> SuggestionBases { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Why are you removing your DbContext class? You still need your DbContext, the only thing you (probably) want to update on deploy is the connection string.

Comment: I kept it, sorry. I edited my main post accordingly.